# check if row value value is equal to column name and access the value of the column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sample dataframe -

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | colfromvaluestobepicked | new col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 'col1' | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 'col2' | 0 |

I want to create a new column whose values are based on if the colfromvaluestobepicked ('col1') is col1 then pick that col value and assign it to the new col and so on.

I am not sure how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for alternative for [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
df1 = df.melt('colfromvaluestobepicked', ignore_index=False)

df['new']=df1.loc[df1['colfromvaluestobepicked'].str.strip("'") == df1['variable'],'value']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df['new col'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row['colfromvaluestobepicked']],axis =1)
```